# Pointer typecasting c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, sizeof

```
#include <iostream>

#define print(x) std::cout << x;
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

int main() {
    int ex[5];
    int* ptr = ex;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ex[i] = 2;
    }
    ex[2] = 3;
    *(int*)((char*)ptr + 8) = 4;
    println(ex[2]);
}
```

on line 13 i'm using (char*) and when i run `println(sizeof(char*))` it says that it's 4 bytes but my instructor says that it's 1 byte long so we need to add 8 bytes to access the value in ex[2], how could this be possible i didn't understand ! :/

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1, `sizeof(char*)` is platform dependent (and on most systems either 4 or 8)

Comment: ```println(sizeof(char*))``` is 4 or 8 bytes based on the architecture. Probably your prof has mentioned it for ```char```

Comment: Line 13 will only reliably modify `ex[2]` and give it a value of `4` if `sizeof(int)` is `4`.    That is not guaranteed.  Although `sizeof(char)` is `1` (by definition) the size of other types (e.g. `sizeof(char *)` and `sizeof(int)` are both implementation-defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the architecture you use. By definition char is the type that has the size of 1, so sizeof(char) evaluates as 1, but it does not automatically mean that it is 8 bits.

To access the next value, you must add sizeof(int) to the pointer to make your code work independent of the architecture it is used on.

When you work with pointers, you tell the compiler that the value the pointer points to takes the space of that type in memory, and the next thing in the memory should be after that amount of units(bytes). So if you cast your int pointer to char pointer, you should add sizeof(int) to your char pointer to have the same effect as you would have added 1 to the int pointer. This is because char is automatically 1 unit by definition, if you would use anything other than char, this would not work, there is no architecture independent specification of sizes of types.

Comment: Thx for your explanation !